# Liquid syntax remove apostrophe

Tags: shopify, liquid

We are trying to solve this issue with an apostrophe in liquid syntax.

We've this value - 'products':'bags' in the variable and we would like to split it and remove the apostrophe.

{% assign values = field | remove: "'" | split: ":" %}

But this is not working.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks ok to me.  When I do

```
{% assign values = "'products':'bags' " | remove: "'" | split: ":" %}
{% for word in values %}
{{ word }}
{% endfor %}
```

I get

```
products

bags
```

What did you want to be different?

Comment: It just didn't work on Drip. I think could be a problem with drip.co